# Routing between 2 networks

Tags: networking, routing

I have an Ubiquiti Edgerouter X that is receiving the internet over PPPoe from a Modem.

The router is configured to have network 192.168.1.0/24 and provide DHCP to devices.

Plugged into one of the ports on the router is a Tenda MW6 Nova Mesh device, which is picking up a DHCP address from the router.  Its then providing 192.168.5.0/24 to the wifi devices, itself being 192.168.5.1 on that network and 192.168.1.184 on the wired network.

Devices on the wifi network can see the internet and access devices on the wired network.  However devices on the wired network can not access devices on the wifi network.  This is by ping, traceroute or ssh.

Now I logged onto the router and tried to add a static route to 192.168.5.0/24 with the next hop being 192.168.1.184 that doesn't seem to have worked.

So I wonder if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

If this is the wrong forum I'm sorry.

[image: Network Diagram Basic]

[image: Route Config]

Answer (score 1):

(Instant upvote for including a diagram of the network setup).

> static route to 192.168.5.0/24 with the next hop being 192.168.1.184

This sounds good, provided your 192.168.1.0/24 boxes receive the Edgerouter address as default route (gateway) via DHCP.

Next thing to check is if the Tenda MW6 does NAT between the "WAN" 192.168.1.184 address and its 192.168.5.0/24. It probably does, because otherwise you'd have to set up static routes on the Tenda. So disable NAT, and configure the Tenda correctly.

Comment: Thanks, having looked I dont seem to be able to switch the NAT off on the tenda device.  It being quite a simple admin interface.  I may be foced to put it in bridge mode, which looses me some functionality.  Around Guest network etc.  I was starting to suspect the tenda.

Comment: Another option would be to put some different firmware on the Tenda (e.g. OpenWRT), if the hardware is supported.